# What is wrong with the following C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, boolean, c-preprocessor

I am using VC2010. I defined FALSE to be false using

```
#define FALSE=false
```

and then I tried to use it as follows

```
bool *bPtr;
if(some condition)
*bPtr=FALSE;
```

the compiler flags FALSE and says "Expected an expression".

I used false instead of the defined 'FALSE' and it accepts it.
I am wondering as what could be the problem.

You might tell me not to define and so not to use FALSE. well, I am not using it.

I just want to know the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put `=` in the definition statement:

```
#define FALSE false
```

The problem is that the preprocessor will replace every `FALSE` with `=false`, so you will have:

```
*bPtr==false;
```

And this is not legal as you see.

Comment: THANKS! I GUESS I WAS BLIND WHEN I DEFINED IT.

Answer (score 6):

Just this:

```
#define FALSE false
```

with whitespace and without `=`.

Answer (score 2):

try defining like this:

```
#ifndef (FALSE)
#define FALSE (0)
#endif
```